# Redirecting SkepticExchange.org traffic

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

I own the domain SkepticExchange.org (and .com). This was the original SEv1.0. I'd like to redirect any traffic to http://skeptics.stackexchange.com when it goes public.

I was able to do this previously by setting up a CNAME record in the zone file:

```
;Configuration for DNS Zone skepticexchange.org

skepticexchange.org. 300 IN SOA ns.rackspace.com hostmaster.rackspace.com (
1274163310
3600
300
1814400
300
)
skepticexchange.org. 86400 IN A 174.143.208.128
skepticexchange.org. 86400 IN NS ns.rackspace.com.
skepticexchange.org. 86400 IN NS ns2.rackspace.com.
www.skepticexchange.org.  86400  IN  CNAME  lbny-se.fogcreek.com.
mail.skepticexchange.org.  86400  IN  CNAME  skepticexchange.org.
```

Is this possible for SEv2? Or should I point at my server and do a simple HTTP redirect?

Comment: Thanks for the generosity!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SO team contacted me and are going to take control of the domains :)

Comment: YOU ROCK! Thanks for being so easy :)

Comment: Thank you! That's amazing generosity.