# Are answers saying a claim is possible allowed?

Tags: discussion, answers

Are answers that state themselves as partial answers and only address if a claim is possible acceptable on this site? My understanding is that an answer needs to address the claim itself and be properly sourced. If an answer just addresses the claim being possible it doesn't actually address the claim itself which may still be false even if it was possibly correct based on the information posted in the answer.

For reference I am asking this question in regards to this answer.

[Was Nikki Haley disqualified from a beauty pageant because of race?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/56618/44152)

Comment: Related prior questions on this topic: [Should answers that are constructive but don't fully answer the question be downvoted?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3225/10630), and [Pseudo-answers are the enemy](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/383/10630)

Answer (score 4):

### "I don't know—but here's some evidence" can be a valid answer

In the past, I've used comments for information that could be seen as a partial answer, but [comments suck](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6534/42375), and I've often seen them deleted. (Yes, that's a link from another SE site where they have far less at stake. The reasoning still applies.) Recently, I've created answers with the information instead:

- [Does chromosome 6 deletion cause the patient to not feel pain, hunger, and fatigue?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/56509/37236) The crux of this question is about a single girl with a rare chromosomal disease, and after searching I don't think the data exists for a good direct answer. Instead, I answered similar but relevant questions like "What symptoms does the condition usually have?" and "Does any non-fatal condition cause these symptoms?"
- [Did Menachem Begin say "I am a former terrorist"?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/56580/37236) This was a partial answer, pure and simple, though it did take quite some time to get that far. I hoped that someone would take the baton and run with it (which did happen, but not to the extent that I feel the question is solved).

As long as you're honest about the strength of the partial answer (and follow the other rules of Skeptics), I don't see a problem with answers like these. Both of mine were well received.

It's awful that we can't immediately get a good answer to every question (but why would Skeptics even exist then?); these answers can serve as a stopgap while others do research, and hopefully make that process easier.

Comment: The Skeptics.SE equivalent to your RPG.SE link about comments sucking: https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2605/should-we-allow-unreferenced-answers-as-comments

Comment: @Oddthinking I still prefer the explanation given on RPG meta. That Skeptics meta link doesn't include half the reasoning they have.

Comment: I am in complete agreement. I just want to reassure readers that the scope of the RPG answer is also applicable here.

Answer (score 2):

I think partial answers are allowed. And establishing that something is historically possible given the time frame rather than the opposite may be helpful. This also goes the other way around, as establishing negative answers is often more difficult, so they're often not saying something is impossible, just rather unlikely.

And although you've promptly downvoted this, generally speaking partial [answers are allowed on SX](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144452/is-it-okay-to-put-partial-answers), which this is one type, I think.

Consider also Skeptics answers like [this](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/56203/29579) which establish no more than someone (but just one) person says they heard something. I consider them a form of partial answers too.

It's also been pointed out (in the long stream of comments under the answer the OP is disputing) that the issue came up on Skeptics meta before:

- [+22/-3 votes](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/389/29579)

> Leaving well referenced partial answers is of help to others as long as the answer isn't noise. [...] Discouraging partial answers is going to be a huge problem when dealing with questions that have a large scope with lots of research [...]

- [+2/0 votes](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3226/29579)

> Remember that constructive referenced answers partially answer the question.

A 2nd answer (from a former diamond mod) on that Q said:

> a fully referenced answer which partially answers the question should not necessarily be downvoted or upvoted. It's up to you.

However it didn't say it should be deleted (as violating site policy etc.)

Comment: Even in that case it doesn't provide much value as the claim can still be true even if unlikely and in that case it could even be worse as it could stop people from looking and confirming it.

Comment: I don't understand your objection to the last answer Is it the hearsay part where the OP quotes someone who quotes someone quoting someone?

Comment: @Oddthinking: It's not exactly and objection since I've accepted that answer. I'm just saying that the kind of certainty the OP seeks is not possible for many historical topics, including the case when there's only one source/witness who wrote about it. We had some recent Qs here about the 14th century ["black hole" in Ottoman history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rise_of_the_Ottoman_Empire), for instance, for which the sources are deemed less credible.

Comment: @Fizz: Oh right. Got it. Thanks. We have to judge historical claims based on the evidence that is available, and sometimes that isn't a high standard.

Answer (score 2):

**Any information is better than none.**

It's long been the case here that partial answers are perfectly OK on Skeptics. Many questions are going to be virtually impossible to get definitive sourced answers for. The linked question is one of those. No news outlet is going to have covered the fact that five year old Nimarata Randhawa was excluded from a segregatedbeauty pageant.

However a partial answer here is absolutely useful. Several people, including the one who asked this question, expressed incredulity and mockery of the very idea that anyone could be excluded from a pageant that allowed both black and white kids to compete (in separate competitions).

What the linked answer does is to give excellent information that such exclusion did in fact happen, and happened fairly frequently. That is useful to know, as it counters the mockery.

This answer dispels the myth of "this is a stupid claim that could never have happened", turning it into "this is something that happened frequently and could well have happened", even if we can't be sure it really happened to Haley.

It is an unfortunate fact about the real world that we don't always get 100% probably true answers to every question. Even where there is clear scientific evidence we can often only say "this is what the scientific consensus is" or "this is what we believe unless new evidence comes along". In that sense all answers are partial answers.

Answer (score 1):

I want to say "It depends", but I am still figuring out what it depends on.

We don't require, but often recommend, that questioners include some short reasoning about *why* they are skeptical.

If this questioner is doubtful that Halley was disqualified from a beauty pageant because they don't think Haley's family would have entered in a competition, or they don't think her parents were from Punjab, or they believe that the whole story was invented by a PR flack, then the answer 'Beauty pageants were segregated by race in that time' is a bad answer.

If the questioner is doubtful about the story purely because they didn't think that pageants at the time were segregated by race or they believed the pageants where strictly white-only, then the answer is very helpful. I would be reluctant to even call it a partial answer (even though it leaves some elements of the claim unexamined).

In this particular case, it is vague. My reading of the question is it is closer to the latter scenario.