# Best practices for editing questions

Tags: discussion, editing

I would like us to collect best practices for editing questions.

Particularly, how should one know when a rephrased question is worth another attempt, and how should one proceed when making revisions? What editing techniques make it more likely that a question will be better received by the community?

Comment: I see no reason to make this question Community Wiki.

Comment: @Borror Your edits/shortening look ok to me.  I was thinking new users could use some hints at editing questions. Perhaps another older meta has such a list already?

Comment: If you think you can improve the question or answer without altering the meaning significantly, edit. See also: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your question phrased as if it's about editing, it's really about asking questions. After all, by wanting what gets a question reopened, you're asking for what differentiates a good question from a bad one.

I covered this [in detail](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/how-can-we-personalize-our-how-to-ask-page/174#174) in the past, but here's what's usually the key point:

- **Put energy in summarizing the position you're skeptical of.** Quoting the exact claim is the surefire and laziest way to do it, but a solid summary is just as good. The idea is to give enough information to the readers so that they understand what you want them to fact-check.

If people have to guess what you mean, you have not done a good job writing (or rewriting) the question. The question must be very clear, to anyone reading it. Most of us can't read minds.