# Indexing the "best-practice" meta-questions

Tags: discussion

I wanted to run an idea up the flag-pole before I implemented it.

I notice I keep coming back to meta to search for links to advise people on best practice for questions and answers.

I had an idea that I would ask a meta-question for an index of the relevant questions (e.g. the two or three meta-q's about references, about images, about potentially offensive topics, and maybe on [editing](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/best-practices-for-editing-questions) and moderating too?) to help me find the right ones and to stop those questions being repeated

I would then provide a CW answer for people to edit. Almost an informal FAQ.

Then I thought I could just go through and tag the relevant questions with a "best-practice" tag instead.

Do either sound useful to you? Is "best-practice" the best word for it?

An a side-question that probably belongs on English Usage.SE. In Commonwealth English practice/practise and licence/license spellings depend on whether it is a noun/verb. In the US, license is always spelt with an 's'. What about practise?

Comment: Progress report: Started to write an FAQ main page. Found @Borror0's question: [What makes a good answer?](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/868/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-answer). That seemed like a good way to go, so added a corresponding [What makes a good question?](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question). That's enough progress for now. Will continue soon.

Comment: Progress report: Added [another question](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/896/what-topics-are-in-and-out-of-scope-of-skeptics-se) about scope and then answered it, which, like the above, which summarises a number of different meta-questions, to make the main FAQ page simpler.

Comment: Progress report: Added a [draft Main FAQ page](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/898/draft-faq-front-page). After the above three questions summarised major parts, the result is far less substantial than I originally invisaged.

Comment: Progress report: Tagged a number of questions as "proposed-faq" and also with "June-2011-faq-revamp" to help moderators find them. [I anticipate that they will remove that last tag as they decide whether they agree.] Over to you @Borror0 and @Fabian.

Comment: I've tried to be (a) helpful, and (b) unbiased towards questions that I have either asked or answered, despite them being by far the most interesting ones (!). If I have failed in either of those goals, my apologies. Please be ruthless in your decisions; I can handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [faq](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) tag that is meant for that, though we haven't consistently applied that one. We should apply that tag to all relevant questions. This is a mod-only tag, so just list the questions here that should have the tag or flag them.

A main FAQ post that would summarize all of the FAQ questions would certainly be useful, there is something like that on Meta.SO.

Comment: Confession: I've never fully understood the FAQ tag. I thought it was somehow protected by moderators. They don't appear [here](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq) nor [here](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq?sort=faq&pagesize=15). I can volunteer to draft a main FAQ post if you like.

Comment: It's a [tag on the meta site](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq), though it can only be applied to questions by mods. It is meant for exactly what you propose to do.

Answer (score 1):

As Fabian said, this is what the FAQ tag is for, but we have been pretty negligent about it. Yesterday, we had only one FAQ-tagged post. We have much more than this.

We'll use this opportunity to play catch up. **Edit your question to list the question you think should have the FAQ applied to. We'll take a look at them** and apply the FAQ tag when applicable.

In the future, I propose we proceed in the following manner to add the FAQ tag to a question:

1. Tag the question with [proposed-faq](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proposed-faq)
2. Open a question about it.

Comment: Okay. I'll write a proposed FAQ main page, with links to the proposed FAQ questions - more than just a list of questions, I'll try to give it some structure.

Comment: Hmmm... just came across your question http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/868/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-answer which is taking the wind out of my sails! Half my job is done for me!

Comment: @Oddthinking: I'm not asking for a "main page" as much as I'm asking for "just list me the question you think need the FAQ tag, so I can apply it."

Comment: understood. Will do. I'm striving for both.